# MVC 4 error for object referance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, object, model-view-controller, reference

This is model:

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Persons
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `DbContext` for the above model class.

```
public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Persons> persons { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller Class:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Person/
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        PersonContext PC = new PersonContext();
        Persons PS = PC.persons.SingleOrDefault(pr => pr.ID == id);
        return View(PS);
    }
}
```

This is my View:

```
'@model MVCDemo.Models.Persons

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>
<h4>Personal Information</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Gender)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Location)
    </dd>

    </dl>
 </div>
 <p>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>'
```

In above bold area i am getting error of

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please tell me the reason why i am getting this error and what is the solution of this.

Comment: Whats your current Url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SingleOrDefault` will return the "default" (which is `null` for reference types, like class instances) if an object is not found matching the conditions given. The most likely reason for the error you describe is your object instances of `Persons` is null.

Comment: So what can i do at the place of SingleOrDefault can i use only Single?

Comment: You need to either check that the value you're passing into the `return View(PS)` statement is not null. This would usually be done as an `if` in your controller, redirecting requests that aren't valid to a page saying "Person not found" or something like that.

Comment: i done this:     PersonContext PC = new PersonContext();
Line 17:             Persons PS = new Persons();
Line 18:             PS = PC.persons.Single(pr => pr.ID == id);
Line 19:             if (PS == null)
Line 20:             {                                                                                                                              Now i m getting this error:Sequence contains no elements

Answer (score 0):

As specified in comments this error is because of Persons objecte becomes null, do a null check like this using null-coalescing operator (`??`)

```
   public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        PersonContext PC = new PersonContext();
        Persons PS = PC.persons.SingleOrDefault(pr => pr.ID == id);
        PS = PS ?? new Persons();
        return View(PS);
    }
```

Comment: Now this  err:-Type 'ASP._Page_Views__ViewStart_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase'.

Comment: This looks like a completely different error, related with your code in viewstart file or configuration.